# Show property of a group element of infinite order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $a\in G$ of infinite order such that $\langle a\rangle \leq G$ (normal subgroup). Show that $g^2a=ag^2$ for each $g\in G$.

Could you give me a hint how we could show that?

EDIT:

Can we do the following?

From definition we have that $g\langle a\rangle g^{-1}=\langle a\rangle$.

So for $a\in \langle a\rangle$ we have for each $g$ $$gag^{-1}=a\Rightarrow ga=ag \Rightarrow gga=gag \Rightarrow g^2a=agg\Rightarrow g^2a=ag^2$$ Using again that $ga=ag$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Do you mean to say that $\langle a\rangle$ is normal in $G$?

Comment: Also, you say you have no idea, but [I don't believe you](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). I think you know a great deal. What you have no idea about is where a finished and polished proof would begin, but that should be the last of your worries.

Comment: I don't think it's true in general. Consider $G=\mathsf{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ with matrix multiplication, $a=\left(\matrix{1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 }\right)$ and $g=\left(\matrix{ 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1}\right)$, for example. Could you provide some more details?

Comment: @EnderWiggins Then $\langle a\rangle$ isn't normal, as $\langle a\rangle$ consists of all upper triangular matrices with $1$ on the diagonal and an integer entry in the top right. But with $g = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}1/2&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, we get $gag^{-1} =\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1/2\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right) \notin\langle a\rangle$. Of course, we haven't yet had _confirmation_ that $\langle a\rangle$ is required to be normal, but I believe it is.

Comment: @Arthur I know. At the beginning I didn't see your first comment. Now, I have decided to leave it there anyway to back up your request.

Comment: Can you take a look at my edited post? @EnderWiggins

Comment: Can you take a look at my edited post? @Arthur

Comment: @MaryStar So is $\langle a \rangle$ normal, as Arthur suggested? Nevertheless, saying that $g\langle a \rangle g^{-1}\subseteq \langle a\rangle$ only tells you that $gag^{-1}=a^n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Yes, it is normal. So what could we do then? @EnderWiggins

Comment: @MaryStar are you asking because you know that it is true and you don't know how to prove it or because you received the assignment to prove it? Because I am not convinced that your statement holds without further assumptions and I am trying to work out a counterexample

Comment: For example, I am tempted to consider the group generated by two elements, $a$ and $b$, subject to the relation $ba=a^2b$. I would dare to say that in such a case $\langle a \rangle$ is normal but the relation doesn't hold

Comment: @EnderWiggins In your example, if $b^{-1}ab=a^n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $a=ba^nb^{-1}=(bab^{-1})^n=a^{2n}$, and thus $a^{2n-1}=1$. So $a$ cannot have infinite order.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Ok, I got it, so that idea doesn't work. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Arnaud for his comment: it showed me the key idea. Since $\langle a \rangle$ is normal in $G$, for every $g\in G$ one has 
$$gag^{-1}=a^n \tag{$\dagger$}\label{dag}$$
for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and 
$$g^{-1}ag=a^{m} \tag{$\star$}\label{ddag}$$
for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore
$$a\stackrel{\eqref{dag}}{=}g^{-1}a^ng = \left(g^{-1}ag\right)^n \stackrel{\eqref{ddag}}{=}a^{mn}.$$
Since $a$ has infinite order, it follows that $mn$ has to be $1$, which means $m=1=n$ or $m=-1=n$. If $m=1=n$ then 
$$ga\stackrel{\eqref{dag}}{=}ag$$
and hence $g^2a=ag^2$. If $m=-1=n$ then 
$$g^2a\stackrel{\eqref{dag}}{=}ga^{-1}g\stackrel{\eqref{ddag}}{=}ag^2.$$

Comment: Or, in other words, since $\langle a\rangle$ is normal, conjugation by $g$ induces an automorphism of it, but the only automorphism of an infinite cyclic group are the identity and inversion (since a generator must be mapped to a generator), which both square to the identity, so $g^2$ commutes with $a$.